# A question about rings of integers and its prime ideals.

Tags: number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and $b\in\mathcal{O}_K^*$. Then is there a good reason to believe that for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$, we can pick some natural number $n$ such that $1+bn$ is 0 modulo $\mathfrak{p}$? This came up on a research paper that I am working on. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Suppose that $-bn\notin\mathfrak{p}$, consider the ideal $I=(-bn,\mathfrak{p})$.

Comment: Do you mean $bn \notin \mathfrak{p}$, for any $n$?

Comment: For some $n$...

Comment: So you are saying that this is true, right?

Comment: @BobDobbs I am unsure about how you are picking $n$ and $\mathfrak{p}$. What is the relation between these two? You said "for some $n$". Do you mean for some $n$, there is a $\mathfrak{p}$ or for every $\mathfrak{p}$ there is some $n$? Obviously when $n=1$, $-bn\notin \mathfrak{p}$, for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: @BobDobbs In your implied hint, I think there is a hard step. As $1 \in (-bn, \mathfrak{p})$, one has that $1 + abn \equiv 0 \bmod \mathfrak{p}$ for some $a \in \mathcal{O}_K$, but I think it is not so obvious how to remove the $a$.

Comment: @davidlowryduda That's right. It cannot work that way.

Comment: In fact, I think this is not true, in general. As an exercise one can try $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)$.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak If you know it is not true why dont you write your counter example as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can look at this example.
Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $b=i$. Then the numbers are of the form $1+in$. Then, for only the primes $\mathfrak{p}$ with $p\equiv 1$ (mod 4), this can be done, where $(p)=\mathfrak{p}\cap \mathbb{Z}$. 
In fact, for general number fields, it will make sense for those primes $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $f(\mathfrak{p}/p)=1$. By the Chebotarev's Density Theorem, we know there are infinitely many of those. But I don't know if this will fail for positive density of primes.